# public object from parent class is null in child class xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, nullreferenceexception, derived-class

Consider this simple `UserControl` *MyUserControl1*.xaml:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Test.CustomControls.MyUserControl1"
x:Name="control" Width="250" Height="100">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBox" x:FieldModifier="public" Text="Hello from the other side !!" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="red"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and it's child *MyUserControl2.xaml* which basically just derive from it, nothing new:

```
<local:MyUserControl1
x:Class="Test.CustomControls.MyUserControl2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test.CustomControls">

</local:MyUserControl1>
```

now let's use the child somewhere:

```
CustomControls.MyUserControl2 control = new CustomControls.MyUserControl2();
MyGrid.Children.Add(control);
control.MyTextBox.Text = "Some text";//NullReferenceException here
```

and I get `NullReferenceException` which basically inform me that `MyTextBox` is null !! What is wrong here?

**P.S.**

1. I gave enough time to this problem and I concluded that this problem occurs when I derive a xaml view from another view and try to access the inner public objects.
2. Both the `MyUserControl1.xaml` and `MyUserControl2` has their code-behind *.cs* files and they just call `InitializeComponent()`, nothing else.

Comment: I'd assumed this should have worked because all controls are added as internal properties to the UC.. but it doesn't! I'd also like to know why?!

Comment: can you simply call something like base.InitializeComponent() of your base class in your child class like basic c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By consulting with my team, the short answer is *not supported*.

It looks like you are wanting to do visual inheritance with XAML with having UI inside the base XAML file to be used.  For XAML, this is not a supported in-box like it was possible for `Winforms`. Here is more information on it along with the restrictions:[UserControl inheritance #100](https://github.com/Microsoft/xaml-standard/issues/100).

If you are creating the user control completed code behind without any XAML, the subclass should work well.